# Making custom Deffered Future Publisher in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

Like the title says I would like to make custom publisher that will basically function like deffered future. Normally when I want to encapsulate code in some Future, but want it to execute on subscription, I would need to write something like this:

```
Deffered {
    Future { promise in
    }
}
```

Now I was thinking of making custom publisher, something along the lines DefferedFuture that will have exact same functionality as Future, but will execute promise only on subscription?

Comment: Since that is exactly what deferred future does already, what new functionality do you need?

Comment: I want to write it as one publisher, not Deffered { Future {} }, just NewDefferedFuture {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious answer is this:

```
func single<Output, Failure>(_ promise: @escaping (@escaping (Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void) -> Void) -> Deferred<Future<Output, Failure>> where Failure: Error {
    Deferred {
        Future<Output, Failure>(promise)
    }
}
```

If it absolutely must be a type rather than a function then:

```
extension Publishers {
    struct Single<Output, Failure>: Publisher where Failure: Error {
        let promise: (@escaping (Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void) -> Void
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            Deferred { Future(promise) }
            .subscribe(subscriber)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a more generic solution, you can use [Ian Keen's AnyPubliser extension](https://gist.github.com/IanKeen/934258d2d5193160391e14d25e54b084) which will allow you to emit more than one value before completing. Something Future doesn't allow.

Comment: Thanks, it must be a type, second part solves it